# golang bind array and input one by one

Tags: go, echo

I am trying to bind the array type and put the values ​​contained in the array one by one

i tried for loop but have json return, so only 1 is stored

like this

```sql
log_id|tag_id|
------+------+
1     |     1|
```

http body

```json
{
    "LogId" : 1
    "tags" : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
}
```

```golang
    var binder struct {
        LogId      uuid.UUID           `json:"logId"`
        TagId      []int32             `json:"tags"`
    }

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(c.Request().Body), &binder)

    err := h.UseCases.CreateReviewLogUseCase.Use(c.Ctx(),
        database.ReviewLogDenyTag{
            LogID: binder.LogId,
            TagID: binder.TagId,
        })

    return c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, map[string]string{
        "message": "success",
    })
```

how to execute like this

```sql
log_id|tag_id|
------+------+
1     |     1|
1     |     2|
1     |     3|
1     |     4|
1     |     5|
1     |     6|
1     |     7|
1     |     8|
1     |     9|
```

thank you

Comment: Look into `for k,v:=range` on how to iterate over any kind of set in golang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your issue is that you're not actually iterating over your list of tags. Every programming language out there has a syntax allowing you to do this, usually called a for-loop. In Go, for loops have a couple of valid syntaxes: `for {starting}; {ending}; {update} {}` like in C, or `for {index}, {value} := range {collection} {}`. The first syntax, although usable, isn't the best for your use case so we'll go with the second. Applying it gives:

```
for _, tag := range binder.TagId {
    err := h.UseCases.CreateReviewLogUseCase.Use(c.Ctx(),
        database.ReviewLogDenyTag{
            LogID: binder.LogId,
            TagID: tag,
        })
}
```

What this is doing is iterating over every entry in `binder.TagId`, which is a slice of integers, and extracting the value and index of each item. In this example we discard the index as it isn't needed and use the value directly.

Comment: Thank you for answer.
But I've already tried it, but only 1 is stored in the database

Comment: @sosolyht Then I would assume that the issue isn't with the looping structure, but how the `CreateReviewLogUseCase.Use` function is handling the data.